# How to show specific data from a database when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a website that currently shows data from my database. I also have some checkboxes. Now I want it to show only the rows that correspond with these checkboxes when the user checks them. This is what I have so far:

Checkboxes:

```
<form>
Actie<input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="actie">
Sport<input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="sport">
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How I show stuff from the database:

```
$con->set_charset("utf8"); 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Product,Prijs,Beschrijving FROM Producten order by     Product ASC LIMIT 0, 5"); 
echo '<table border="1px solid black" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:47px"><tbody>'; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{  
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td rowspan='2' width= '200'>" . $row['Product'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td><b>" . $row['Product'] . "</b></td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['Beschrijving'] . "&nbsp;<i>Prijs: &euro;&nbsp;" . $row['Prijs'] . "    </i><br/><br/></td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 

}
```

I know I can use WHERE to show only the data I want, I just don't know how to do this only when a checkbox is checked.

Comment: What will be the column to filter on the checkbox value ?

Comment: The chackbox value is in a column called Genre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if($_POST['genre']!=""){
$query="SELECT Product,Prijs,Beschrijving FROM Producten order by WHERE genre=".$_POST['genre']."    Product ASC LIMIT 0,5";
 }
 else{
 $query="SELECT Product,Prijs,Beschrijving FROM Producten order by Product ASC LIMIT 0,5";
}
$con->set_charset("utf8"); 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
echo '<table border="1px solid black" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:47px"><tbody>'; 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
 {  
 echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td rowspan='2' width= '200'>" . $row['Product'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td><b>" . $row['Product'] . "</b></td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['Beschrijving'] . "&nbsp;<i>Prijs: &euro;&nbsp;" . $row['Prijs']."</i><br/><br/></td>"; 
 echo "</tr>"; 

}
```

Comment: I tried this. When I don't check anything I get:
Notice: Undefined index: genre in /var/www/games.php on line 49 ---> if($_POST['genre']!=""){
When I do check a box I get:
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/games.php on line 50 ---> $query="SELECT ......

 And I get: 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/games.php on line 58 ---> while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Answer (score 0):

You can check if genre has a value or is set.

```
if ($_POST['genre'] != "")
{
  ...
}
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST['genre']))
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Product,Prijs,Beschrijving FROM Producten";
if(isset($_POST['genre'])){
    $sql .= " WHERE Producten.`genre` IN (";
    $genres = implode(',', $POST['genre']);
    $genres = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $genres) . "'";
    $sql .= $genres;
    $sql .= ")";
}

$sql .= " order by Product ASC LIMIT 0, 5";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Secondly, you need to replace

```
Actie<input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="actie">
Sport<input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="sport">
```

with

```
Actie<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="actie">
Sport<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="sport">
```